# Service Worker is not active in Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Angular 9 and I implemented Service worker in my app, after "build --prod" and lunch with "http-server" in Firefix service worker cache normal all what I need but in Chrome it doesn't want to cache, even I implemented https in my app, after I start app it works on https://localhost:44363. Any idea how to make Chrome happy and start to cache files of my app?

Comment: Did you check in the chrome console about service workers?

Comment: yes, service worker is active and no errors in console!